# Check if webpage doesn't block being included in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

On my website can create something like `presentation` and one functions of site is `Add object - website`. After click, new `iframe` is created with typed website `URL`. But some websites, for example google and facebook, are unable to be insterted via iframe. So I need to create prevention to check, if is site able to be in the `iframe`, when not, alert will be displayed.

Before posting this question as duplicate:

**I need to use only JavaScript (or jQuery), my website works on Java, so don't post me answers with PHP codes or other languages!!!**

Comment: What the back end uses is immaterial and so this is nothing to do with Java. You should probably untag "Java" before people start marking your Q down. There is no link between Javascript and Java outside of them both being languages.

Comment: I know, that JS and Java has no connection, but I just thought, if my page works on Java, then there could be some solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried jQuery error method.

```
$( "<iframe-id>" ).error(function() {
  alert("invalid url")
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested it (http://jsfiddle.net/ugJ45/) but it doesn't work for me. Here I paste `fiddle` source, can you edit it, if I am doing something wrong?